# "Could not find schema information for the element" - but my schema file does contain information for the element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to work with an application that i don't have the source code for.  I'm trying to interface in some data in an XML file.  i believe my file matches the applications required schema correctly, but i get the message "Could not find schema information for the element" for every element in my file.  I've decomplied the applications code and rebuilt it in visual studio, and i get the error myself.

I'm going to go ahead and just dump the code... Its pretty long, but i'm starting to think its a pretty bone head mistake on my part.

The XML to be imported:

```
<WorkOrders>
    <WorkOrder>
        <Action>SAVE</Action>
        <UserDef1>NotRequired1</UserDef1>
        <UserDef2>NotRequired2</UserDef2>
        <UserDef3>NotRequired3</UserDef3>
        <UserDef4>NotRequired4</UserDef4>
        <UserDef5>NotRequired5</UserDef5>
        <UserDef6>NotRequired6</UserDef6>
        <UserDef7>-1</UserDef7>
        <UserDef8>-2</UserDef8>
        <AutoRelease>N</AutoRelease> <!--Probably can hardcode as N-->
        <BuildInstructions>Not Required BuildInstructions</BuildInstructions>
        <!--<BuildLocation>Not required BuildLocation</BuildLocation>-->
        <Company></Company> <!--should match compan on the item master-->
        <!--<DimensionUm></DimensionUm>-->
        <DueDate>12-31-2011</DueDate>
        <!--<Error></Error>-->
        <FinishedItem>SERIAL_TEST</FinishedItem>
        <QtyToBeBuilt>12345</QtyToBeBuilt>
        <!--<QtyUm></QtyUm>
        <RevisionNum></RevisionNum>-->
        <Warehouse>PPLant</Warehouse>
        <WeightUm></WeightUm>
        <WOAllocMethod></WOAllocMethod>
        <WorkOrderDetails>
            <Action>SAVE</Action>
            <UserDef1>NotRequired1</UserDef1>
            <UserDef2>NotRequired2</UserDef2>
            <UserDef3>NotRequired3</UserDef3>
            <UserDef4>NotRequired4</UserDef4>
            <UserDef5>NotRequired5</UserDef5>
            <UserDef6>NotRequired6</UserDef6>
            <UserDef7>-1</UserDef7>
            <UserDef8>-2</UserDef8>
            <AllocationRule>WorkOrderAllocation</AllocationRule>
            <BuildLevel>1</BuildLevel>
            <!--<BuildSequence>1</BuildSequence>-->
            <Company></Company>
            <ComponentItem>SERIAL_TEST</ComponentItem>
            <FromLocation></FromLocation>-->
            <!-- these fields allow users to increase/decrease the component quantity required
            <IncQtyAmount></IncQtyAmount>
            <IncQtyEligible></IncQtyEligible>
            <IncQtyMinAmount></IncQtyMinAmount>
            <IncQtyType></IncQtyType>-->
            <!-- <LogisticsUnit></LogisticsUnit>
            <Lot></Lot>
            <ParentLogisticsUnit></ParentLogisticsUnit>-->
            <QtyNeededPerItem>10</QtyNeededPerItem>
            <!--<QuantityUm></QuantityUm>-->
            <Warehouse>PPLant</Warehouse>
        </WorkOrderDetails>
        <WorkOrderId>ExampleWorkOrderID001</WorkOrderId>
        <AllocationRule>WorkOrderAllocation</AllocationRule>

    </WorkOrder>
</WorkOrders>
```

The schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="WorkOrderDownload" targetNamespace="http://www.asdf.com/asdfNET/Interface" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.asdf.com/asdfNET/Interface" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2008">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="InterfaceEntity.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="WorkOrders" nillable="false" type="WorkOrderList" />
    <xs:complexType name="WorkOrderList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WorkOrder" nillable="true" type="WorkOrder" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="WorkOrder">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AutoRelease" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BuildInstructions" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BuildLocation" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Company" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DimensionUm" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DueDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Error" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FinishedItem" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InterfaceEntity" type="InterfaceEntity" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InternalWorkOrderNum" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemClass" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemColor" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemCost">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemDescription" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemHeight">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemLength">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemSize" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemStyle" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemValue">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemWeight">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemWidth">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PlannedUnitBuildTime">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="QtyToBeBuilt">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="QtyUm" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RevisionNum">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VolumeUm" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Warehouse" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WeightUm" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WOAllocMethod" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WorkOrderDetails" type="WorkOrderDetailList" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WorkOrderId" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="WorkOrderDetailList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WorkOrderDetail" nillable="true" type="WorkOrderDetail" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="WorkOrderDetail">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AllocationRule" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BuildLevel">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BuildSequence">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Company" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ComponentItem" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FromLocation" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IncQtyAmount" type="xs:double" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IncQtyEligible" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IncQtyMinAmount">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IncQtyType" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InterfaceEntity" type="InterfaceEntity" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InternalWorkOrderNum">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LogisticsUnit" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Lot" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ParentLogisticsUnit" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="QtyNeededPerItem">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="QuantityUm" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Warehouse" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace WorkOrderInterfaceValidation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            helper h = new helper();
            h.main();
        }
    }

    class helper
    {
        StringBuilder _valErrorMsgs;

        public helper()
        {
            _valErrorMsgs = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void main()
        {
            try
            {
                string error = "No error";
                Console.WriteLine("hello world");

                ValidateSchemaWithURI("C:\\Program Files\\software\\asdf\\2010\\Interface\\Input\\ExampleWorkOrder001.xml",
                    "http://www.asdf.com/asdfNET/Interface",
                    "\\\\localhost\\asdf\\Schemas\\Interface\\WorkOrderDownload.xsd",
                    out error
                    );

                error += " err";
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public XmlReader ValidateSchemaWithURI(string inputUri, string targetNamespace, string schemaPath, out string error)
        {
            //StringBuilder _valErrorMsgs = new StringBuilder();
            XmlReader reader = null;
            XmlReader reader2;
            try
            {
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.Schemas.Add(targetNamespace, schemaPath);
                settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
                settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(this.SchemaValidationEventHandler);
                reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUri, settings);

                foreach (var v in settings.Schemas.Schemas())
                {
                    foreach (var e in ((XmlSchema)v).Attributes)
                    {
                        e.ToString();
                    }
                }

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                }
                reader2 = reader;
            }
            catch (XmlException exception)
            {
                _valErrorMsgs.Append(exception.Message).Append(";");
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                reader2 = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                error = _valErrorMsgs.ToString();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            return reader2;
        }

        private void SchemaValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
        {
            this._valErrorMsgs.Append(args.Exception.Message).Append(";");
        }
    }
}
```

The error message:

> XmlException: Could not find schema information for the element 'WorkOrders'.;Could not find schema information for the element 'WorkOrder'.;Could not find schema information for the element 'Action'.;Could not find schema information for the element 'UserDef1'.;Could not find schema information for the element 'UserDef2'.;Could not find schema information for the element 'UserDef3'.;Could not find schema information for the element 'UserDef4'.;Could not find schema information for the ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the namespace. Try:

```
<WorkOrders xmlns="http://www.manh.com/ILSNET/Interface">
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue though my xml and xsd both contain the same target namespace as you defined. any ideas?